# Average Velocity or Instantaneous Velocity?

Tags: calculus

Suppose d(t) measures distance traveled in feet at time "t" seconds. State whether each of the following represents **Average Velocity** or **Instantaneous Velocity.**

$$\frac{{d(11) - d(6)}}{{11 - 6}}$$

---

$$ d'(4)$$

---

slope of the tangent line at t=5

---

slope of the secant line through the points (3,d(3)) and (7,d(7))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d(11)−d(6)}{11−6}$$ is an average velocity, over the interval $[11,6]$.
$$d^{'}(4)$$ is an instantaneous velocity, at $t=4$.
$$\mbox{slope of tangent line at $t=5$ is just }d^{'}(5)$$which is the instantaneous velocity at $t=5$.
$$\mbox{slope of the secant line through the points (3,d(3)) and (7,d(7))}$$
is the average slope of the secant line over the interval $[3,7]$.